# How to access resources folder outside of the war in spring boot

Tags: spring, unix

I have a rest API written in Spring Boot that has to be deployed on a weblogic server on Unix. I have some property files and DRL files in src/resources folder. I want to place all these files on a Unix location and access them in my application. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

When you want Spring to look outside the project folder you want:

```
"file:/Users/username/MyDirectory/file.txt"
```